# How to grant access subdomain/folder exclusively one IP?

Tags: .htaccess, ip, subdomain

I am curious how to grant traffic from only one IP (public ip) access to one folder on a subdomain?

So for example:
I have a public IP form my DSL provider (home use) and only fromout my house I can access subdomain.example.com/test/index.html and subdomain.example.com/test/info/info.html

i have heard from a .htaccess file but in which directory do I have to place this file and what should be IN it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow.com  I would suggest you put your `.htaccess` file in `subdomain.example.com/test/` and add the following code to your .htaccess file

**.htaccess**

```
<LIMIT GET>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from  192.168.0.18
</LIMIT>
```

make sure you change 192.168.0.18, to the ip address you want to allow access too.  I tested this with my own server, *chrisrjones.com/test/test.html* And I'm only able to access this page from my WAN IP not my cell phone.

Also this -> is a good read,
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html